# Xpages get mail file from lotus

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is there a way to get the value of the mail file field from the (Company)' Directory ? I wrote a code to get the value but it is not the same in all situation.
Here is the code:

```
var firstChar = context.getUser().getFullName().charAt(0);
var lastWord = context.getUser().getFullName().split(" ").pop();

var str = firstChar+lastWord;
var str2 = str.slice(0, 8);

var link = "https://server/mail/";
link +=str2+".nsf/iNotes/Mail/?OpenDocument&ui=portal";
return link;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the server directory as any other Notes database. Unless additional address books are there, the user should exist under their username in the "($Users)" view. From there you can retrieve the mail file and server. If it's different from the current server, you may need to check the relevant server document for the hostname.

Comment: With @DbColumn(@DbName(),"$Users",x) ?? Or how?

Comment: You're better off using session.getDatabase() etc

Comment: You'd be better off using the LookupNames method of the NotesDirectory class in order to avoid the possible issue of mulitple address books. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDIRECTORY_CLASS.html  (I'm not an xPages guy, so I'm assuming this class is exposed there, somehow.)

Comment: Yes, it should be available. All LotusScript methods are available in Java / SSJS

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing an example from the documentation on the NotesDirectory class and modifying for your purposes, I'd try something like:

```
var mynotesdir:NotesDirectory = session.getDirectory("server name");        
var homeserver =  mynotesdir.GetMailInfo("Joe Smith", True);

var mailFileName = homeserver[3];
var link = "https://server/mail/" + mailFileName + "/iNotes/Mail/?OpenDocument&ui=portal";
return link;
```

The syntax may be wrong, as I copied it from an example and modified it here instead of in Designer, but this should still serve as a good start.....